# Outlook 15.27 Ctrl-A and Ctrl-E shortcuts no longer working

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

I *often* have to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> shortcuts to get to the start and end of lines in Outlook, and it looks like in the latest version (15.27), these no longer work.  Instead <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> behaves like Windows and selects everything, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> doesn't seem to do anything.

I can't figure out anything in settings or another way to override this behavior - has anyone encountered this or figured out a workaround?

Comment: https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293343-outlook-for-mac/suggestions/15296547-support-macos-keyboard-shortcuts also mentions the change of behaviour but sadly there's no resolution at the time of writing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this out and can confirm that this did stop working.  However, there is a quick and easy fix: you can set your keyboard command in ***Customize Keyboard*** directly in Word.

Under the **Tools** Menu in Word, select **Customize Keyboard** (it's at the very bottom)

[image]

Next, in the ***Categories*** tab, select "All Commands."  Then in the ***Commands*** search for "endofline".  You can then assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>

[image]

Make sure you are saving to *Normal.dot* (the default template) and select "OK."  You should have your keyboard shortcut restored.

Comment: These are excellent instructions, and they work for changing the keyboard behavior within Word itself.  But, tragically, it seems Outlook no longer respects the Word preferences, at least as of Outlook 15.38.